# Mac proj.4 compile error

Tags: c, macos, homebrew, proj

I installed proj.4 library with homebrew on my Mac 10.7 (using gcc-4.2). When trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <proj_api.h>


int main(void) {
    projPJ pj_merc;
    pj_merc = pj_init_plus("+proj=merc");
    pj_free(pj_merc);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
$ gcc-4.2 test.c 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_pj_init_plus", referenced from:
      _main in cccf4vey.o
  "_pj_free", referenced from:
      _main in cccf4vey.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**EDIT:**
The library file is 64bit (`gcc-4.2 -m32 test.c` lead to the same error):

```
$ file /usr/local/lib/libproj.dylib 
/usr/local/lib/libproj.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: did you install the 64 bit version of the library? Do you get the same error when using the gcc flag to compile 32 bit code as well?

Comment: This might be a dumb question but is the library pre-built .o files or are they .so files that you have to use -lproj_api? I'm asking because I'm unsure of the library as I've never heard of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should link against the library.

```
gcc-4.2 test.c -L/usr/local/lib -lproj
```

This is what the error is complaining about

Comment: @Jesus I hadn't seen your comment before I posted the answer, It's one of those typical errors when starting to use external libraries. The whole framework idea makes using external libraries much easier as it carries along the -I, -L and -l options